# bash: /usr/bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file

Tags: bash, docker-compose

i have a `docker-compose.yaml` file as below and it should bring up a container and run a simple command such as `pwd` or `echo hellllo` in this container:

```
 version: '3'

services:
  remote_interpreter :
    image: amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01

    command: -i "pwd"
```

However, when i run `docker-compose -f ./my-file.yaml up` then it complains with:

```
 bash: /usr/bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
```

if i try with `command: sh -c "pwd"` and i got:

`/usr/bin/sh: /usr/bin/sh: cannot execute binary file`

I understand that the error means the command `pwd` is not seen as compiled file for `bash`, but i still don't know how to fix it ?!

Comment: bash is not _supposed_ to run `pwd` as a file; `pwd` is a built-in. If you override the faulty `aws-glue-libs` image to invoke the shell correctly (as will result from applying the answer that's already present), it'll use that built-in instead of trying to invoke an external command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the `entrypoint` [baked into the image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/amazon/aws-glue-libs/glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01/images/sha256-a29a8366e64b68749d8fa3756dae75fd21a5f628e09dafadb6923cedd7723e72?context=explore):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash" "-l"]
```

That seems wrong to me. The list should be comma-separated, not space-separated.

Resetting the entrypoint makes the `command` work for me

```
version: '3'

services:
  remote_interpreter :
    image: amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01
    entrypoint: ""
    command: "pwd"
```

Or, you could actually make the entrypoint work, and use:

```
version: '3'

services:
  remote_interpreter :
    image: amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01
    entrypoint: [bash, -l, -c]
    command: "pwd"
```

which will result in `bash -l -c "pwd"` to be executed.

To be clear: this is not really a `docker-compose` issue. The issue is not using `bash -c` for executing `pwd`. This is outside docker:

```bash
$ cd /tmp
$ bash pwd
/usr/bin/pwd: /usr/bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
$ bash -c pwd
/tmp
```

The reason your second attempt (`command: sh -c "pwd"`) failed is because it would execute `bash -l sh -c "pwd"`, which is again an execution of `sh` without `-c` (`command` is appended to `entrypoint`).

Besides the wrong syntax in the original entrypoint, having `bash -l` as an entrypoint doesn't make much sense imho.

Comment: Yes, removing the entrypoint worked for me. Also fixing it (second option)

Comment: I know you didn't. It's the entrypoint that is baked into the image (see the link in my answer) that is wrong and you should override it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have still one related question. When i do the `command: "pip3 install --user pyspark pyspark-test pytest boto3 jsonpath_ng"`, i still do not find some of these packages ,such as `pyspark`, in my container. Do you have any idea ?